# How to say "Please correct my sentences"?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

Is it: 文章を治てください？

There are many words for "correct' including 改める, 正す, 訂する, but it's not clear when to use those words or which is "correct" in this context.

Comment: 文章を直してください is correct. 治す is used like 病気を治す.

Answer (score 7):

文章を[直]{なお}してください is fine. You can also say 書いた文を[訂正]{ていせい}してください because 訂正 gets used a lot and implies that you gotta correct something. You don't use [正]{ただ}す, [訂]{てい}する in daily speech and [改]{あらた}める is used for intangible things like behavior or speech.

PS for the Korean version look at the very bottom of this page.

### CLARIFICATION

1. [訂正]{ていせい} means *fix an error* and implies that you know there is some error. When a worker creates a piece of work (designs a poster, writes a manual, makes an excel spreadsheet) and you find an error, you can tell them to「訂正してください」 which is the same as 「直してください」
2. [添削]{てんさく}, recommended in the comments, means to *go over someone's **writing** and correct it if necessary*, and may apply to your case. You can use it for written papers and exams, but not for math tests (where the error would be a math error as opposed to spelling or grammar)

If you are not sure which to go for, I suggest saying something more general like

> 間違いがあるかどうかチェックしてもらえますか？

Comment: I find 「訂正」 to be a poor word choice here because that means "correcting one's OWN mistakes".  I would definitely use 「[添削]{てんさく}」.

Comment: A better phrasing might use 敬語, like ていただけませんか and other variants

Comment: Just here to back up 添削, as when Japanese people come to me asking me to correct their Norwegian they use 添削. :)