# How to say "correction/to correct" in the school/university context?

Tags: word-choice

It is possible that this question appears as a duplicate of this [one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30651/how-to-say-please-correct-my-sentences). Nonetheless, in contrast to the latter, my question here is specifically targeted towards the context of the school/university and the teacher-student relationship, and touches upon other possible meanings of the English "correction/to correct" (for instance (3), and the notion of grading in (2) and (3)).

How do we say "correction"/"to correct" in the school/university context, that is:

(1) the fact that the professor corrects the students sentences during the class

(2) the fact that the professor corrects the students homework (which can imply a grading)

(3) the fact that the professor corrects the students exam (which implies a grading)

For (1), I suppose that 直す or 訂正する could be used.

For (2), I suppose it would be 添削. What about if the homework is graded?

For (3), I have no idea.

Comment: 3) is a duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96011/how-to-say-to-grade-in-japanese-school-university-system/96015#96015.

Comment: I believe 2) and 3) are sometimes referred to as 採点する, if the emphasis is on grading instead of fixing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

添削 is literally *adding and deleting*, so 添削する can be used if a professor makes corrections (e.g. in red) to students' compositions on blackboard or notebook. It works for 1, and for 2 and 3, too. Though 添削 does NOT exclude scoring, it is less natural for corrections with scoring.

採点 is literally *taking the score*, so 採点する implies grading. It works for 2 and 3.

---

直す is a broad word for fixing, so can be used for 1 and 2 (usually no scoring).

訂正する is less likely to be used in the context. I feel that it usually refers to some sort of rectifying. E.g., 発言を訂正する means *to correct what the subj. said*.

---

Another (perhaps very Japanese) word is 丸をつける/丸付けする because the Japanese use circles to mark the correct answer. It is mostly synonymous to 採点する.

And note that 添削する is not very commonly used for marking yes/no exams or most science subjects because there are usually no corrections. I guess 採点/丸付け is more normal.

Comment: I wish the Japanese SE uses circles, too :P.

Comment: Thank you. Speaking about "correction/to correct", with your answer and my personal investigation, I found that 修正する can really not be used for the meanings (1), (2) and (3) mentioned in my question. Is it right? But I suppose it could be used (4) for a university student correcting his or her master thesis, or phd thesis after some remarks were given by the tutor. (5) for a researcher correcting his or her manuscript after some remarks were given by peers outside a peer review process, by peers in the peer review process, and by the editor of the journal for the final version. Is it right?

Comment: @starckman Yes, 修正する is, like 訂正する, unlikely to be used for the context, but fine for 4. It sounds more correcting one's own mistakes. As for 5, to some extent yes (if it is about obvious errors).  My impression is that usually people just say 'thank you for reading/pointing out errors' (間違い・誤りを指摘する for the latter) in acknowledgments. FYI (professional) proofreading is 校正する.